# C# operator overload members mirroring

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Today I've encountered a problem with operators overloading. I have a class

```
public sealed class StringIdentifier : IIdentifier
{
  private readonly string _identifier;


  public StringIdentifier(string identifier)
  {
    _identifier = identifier;
  }


  public object GetIdentifier()
  {
    return _identifier
  }

 
  public static implicit operator StringIdentifier(string value) => new StringIdentifier(value);
  public static implicit operator string(StringIdentifier value) => value._identifier;

  public static bool operator ==(StringIdentifier a, string b) => a?._identifier == b;
  public static bool operator !=(StringIdentifier a, string b) => a?._identifier != b;
}
```

The problem is, that checking `if (StringIdentifier == string)` uses the written bool operator, however, using `if (string == StringIdentifier)` does 2 implicit conversions (thus creates single garbage object (StringIdentifier)) to meet the format `operator ==(StringIdentifier a, string b)`.

I know this can be solved by writing the same operator overload just switching the members (i.e. `public static bool operator ==(string a, StringIdentifier b)`, however, that just creates more methods (and pretty much duplicates the code) but logically nothing is changed.

My question is, is there a way to do automatic operator members mirroring (`StringIdentifier == string` would be mirrored as `string == StringIdentifier`), so that I would not need to write same comparison overload twice (or call switched members comparison in overload)?

Comment: No, there isn't (unless you include the code generation available in C# 9, which you could probably use). You might also want to edit your question title to refer to overloading rather than overriding.

Comment: As an aside, it's unclear to me why you're casting `value._identifier` (which is already of type `string`) to `string` in the `implicit operator string(StringIdentifier value)`

Comment: "thus creates single garbage object" Does this really matter though? Are you sure you are not optimising prematurely?

Comment: @JonSkeet actually, this is operator overriding (overriding default operator behaviour), but creating multiple operator definitions is overloading. I think the title is actually correct as I'm talking about member mirroring in an override. As for conversion, that was a blooper from me, it used to be `GetIdentifier()` method used, which returned `object` and had to be cast. Will edit my question to fix it. Thanks for noting that. 

Comment: @tsvedas: the correct term in C# and other languages is [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/operator-overloading?view=msvc-160) anyway :)

Comment: @Sweeper agree, it might be seen as premature optimization. Depends on how you look at it, actually. This point's primary goal was not to improve performance, but just to satisfy a preference to not create objects that are not needed.

Comment: It is called "operator overloading".It gives the language a new way to resolve the same operator. *I believe that is why.*

Comment: @tsvedas: No, it's really not operator overriding. There is no such concept in C#. (Overriding is associated with execution-time behavior based on actual types; that's not used at all in operator lookup.)

Comment: Agree, my mistake. Title updated.